# Can i Access iPhone/iPad VPN Settings

Tags: iphone, ipad

Can i access/control iPhone/iPad VPN settings programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. You can however create a profile and have a link to download and install it in the app, that's what Onavo (http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onavo-save-data-stretch-your/id423545287?mt=8) is doing.

Comment: And Junos Pulse. But login to VPN is done within the Junos Pulse App, which then launches the VPN. I don't know how they do it. (Works this way on iOS 7).